# MatTableDataSource return a promise for ~ 7000 lines

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, angular-material, angular7

I have a problem when try to put a lot of data in `mattabledatasource`, I want at leas to display a loader but I don't know when data is already set. I try to use a promise like that :

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.infos.map(info => {
        info.members.map(member => {
            member.contacts.map(contact => {
                dataSource.push({
                    contact,
                    member
                });
            });
        });
    });
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(dataSource);
    resolve();
});
```

But not working, just my table is freezing 10 seconds. How I can know when all maps + set data source is done ? Thx in advance.

Comment: Promises do not (by default) enable parallel programming for JS. Long running code like this will still block the main thread. You're probably looking for [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use async and await.

> 1. table already got the hole amount of data with async method

> 2. dataSource is ready to create the table.

```
  async buildTable() {
    this.infos.map(info => {
      info.members.map(member => {
        member.contacts.map(contact => {
          dataSource.push({
            contact,
            member
          });
        });
      });
    });

    await Promise.all(dataSource).then((tableData) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(tableData)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Async/await will not help here.

Comment: Ok, sorry then. I thought it can be a good idea.

Comment: no need to apologise. It doesn't help because async/await is syntax "sugar" for promises. Promises fundamentally won't stop long running code from freezing the page, _unless_ that code is put in a web worker, or in another page/resource.